# Text search and replace other text on the same line

Tags: windows, gratis, text-search

I have code in a directory tree, with lots of sub-directories.

The function `foo()` takes two parameters,. which will generally be different for each call.

I want to add a third, which every caller has a variable in a variable named `debug`.

I want to recurse the directory tree, find every call to `foo(x, y)` or `foo(a,b)` or `foo(1,2)` and add the `debug` parameter, so that they become `foo(x, y, debug)`, etc

I want a gratis Windows program that will all me to search a filename with wildcards and recurse through the directory tree, finding each line with `foo(` and changing each `)` to `, debug)`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) There you can use the Find in Files function, do a regex search with your replace parameter.

You will fill the root directory path, check the `In all sub-folders` option, mark the `Regular Expression` option and fill the parameter as:

Find what: `(foo\(.+?,.+?)\)`

Replace with: `$1, debug\)`

Comment: Lolx! I meant to delete the question before going to bed last night, as that is exactly the conclusion that I had reached. Good that you answered, though, as others can now search for this.  I will leave the question open for a bit, in the unlikely case that someone has a non-regexp solution. When no one has posted one, I will award you the answer. Welcome aboard!

Comment: No tool for n00bs, then :-/  I accpet this as the answer, since it does just what I want. Now I have two problems :-)

Comment: Regex heheheheh :) Take a time to learn it then you goes back to only one :)